# Найти степень двойки

Tags: python, математика

Накопал в гугле такой код:

```
n = int(input())
if n & (n - 1) :
    print("NO")
else:
    print("YES")
```

Единственное, не совсем понимаю как он работает, и как вывести степень?
То есть, я например ввожу `n = 8` программа должна вывести `3`

Comment: Этот код проверяет, является ли число степенью двойки. Для вашей задачи он не подойдет.

Comment: То есть, только перебором через for?

Comment: Почему только перебором. Можно через логарифм. Возможно есть другие способы. Смотря какие ограничения задачи (если они есть).

Comment: `print(math.log2(8))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вот целых два способа:

```
n = int(input())
m = 1
i = 0
while m <= n:
    if m==n:
        print(i)
        break
    else:
        m = m*2
        i = i+1
if m > n:
    print("No")


j = 0
while n != 1:
    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n/2
        j = j + 1
    else:
        break

if n == 1:
    print(j)
else:
    print("No")
```

Answer (score 1):

Решить задачу можно либо перебором, либо через логарифм(вот пример кода перебора):

```
n = int(input())
c = 0
for i in range(0, 1000):
    if 2 ** i == n:
        c += 1
        print(i)
if c == 0:
    print("НЕТ")
```

Comment: Есть проблема, не сработает с числом 21430172143725346418968500981200036211228096234110672148875007767407021022498722449863967576313917162551893458351062936503742905713846280871969155149397149607869135549648461970842149210124742283755908364306092949967163882534797535118331087892154125829142392955373084335320859663305248773674411336138752

Comment: Для этого, можно поменять значение в for до предельного, просто у меня предел был 1000, поэтому я не заморачивался)

Comment: Чтобы не было явно прописанного числа, можно через деление сделать.

Comment: Если предел 1000, то range нужно делать до 1001.  А вот редундантный 0 можно и убрать